# Extract string between two special characters in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to extract a list with strings that are between two special characters (= and ;).
Below is an example of the file with line types and the needed strings in bold.
File is a quite big one, type is xml.

```
<type="string">data source=**HOL4624**;integrated sec>
<type="string">data source=**HOL4625**;integrated sec>
```

I managed to find the lines matching “data source=”, but how to get the name after?
Used code is below.

```
Get-content regsrvr.txt | select-string -pattern "data source="
```

Thank you very much!

```
<RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">data source=HOL4624;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=False;trustservercertificate=False;packet size=4096</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>

<RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">data source=HOL4625;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=False;trustservercertificate=False;packet size=4096</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show the actual XML (replacing sensitive data, if needed); this one is not valid. It looks like SQL Server's connection string, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Dear vonPryz, yes SQL server registered servers xml. It doesn't let me paste the actual code. I will add the lines matching 'data source=' - what interest me.

Answer (score 1):

The XML is not valid, so it's not a clean parse, anyway you can use string split with regex match:

```
$html = @"
<RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">data source=HOL4624;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=False;trustservercertificate=False;packet size=4096</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>
<RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">data source=HOL4625;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=False;trustservercertificate=False;packet size=4096</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>
"@

$html -split '\n' | % {$null = $_ -match 'data source=.*?;';$Matches[0]} | 
% {($_ -split '=')[1] -replace ';'}

HOL4624
HOL4625
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the connectionstring is for SQL Server, let's use .Net's [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to do all the work for us. Like so,

```
# Test data, XML extraction is left as an exercise
$str = 'data source=HOL4624;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=False;trustservercertificate=False;packet size=4096'

$builder = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder($str)

# Check some parameters
$builder.DataSource                                                                                             
HOL4624


$builder.IntegratedSecurity                                                                                     
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expand your try at using `Select-String` with a better use of regex. Also, you don't need to use `Get-Content` first. Instead you can use the `-Path` parameter of `Select-String`.

The following Code will read the given file and return the value between the `=` and `;`:

```
(Select-String -Path "regsrvr.txt" -pattern "(?:data source=)(.*?)(?:;)").Matches | % {$_.groups[1].Value}
```

---

**Pattern Explanation (RegEx):**

You can use `-pattern` to capture an String given a matching RegEx. The Regex can be describe as such:

`(?:` opens an non-capturing Group

`data source=` matches the charactes `data source=`

`)` closes the non-capturing Group

`(.*?)` matches any amount of characters and saves them in a Group. The `?` is the lazy operator. This will stop the matching part at the first occurence of the following group (in this case the `;`).

`(?:;)` is the final non-capturing Group for the closing `;`

---

**Structuring the Output**

`Select-String` returns a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`-Object.

You can find the matched Strings (the whole String and all captured groups) in there. We can also loop through this Output and return the Value of the captured Groups: `| % {$_.groups[1].Value}`

`%` is just an Alias for `For-Each`.

For more Informations look at the [`Select-String`-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1) and try your luck with some [RegEx](https://regexr.com/).